# How to address files on Desktop

Tags: command-line, directory

Via terminal, I tried to address a file or directory on my desktop (Ubuntu 18) but even this simple command bounces each time: no directory or no file.
command used in terminal is

```
cd/home/"my username"/Desktop/"directory name"
```

f.i. an extracted directory from a `*.tar.gx` file. 
Even accessing Desktop results in:

```
bash: cd/home/jos_mp/Desktop/: No such file or directory
```

Username "jos_mp"  is result of `pwd` command.
Here stop the basics already !

Comment: I recommend reading a `bash` guide like the [Bash Guide for Beginners from tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the space between the command name `cd` and the argument (the path):

```bsh
cd /home/$USER/Desktop/"directory name" # or:
cd ~/Desktop/"directory name" # or, if you’re already in ~/Desktop:
cd "directory name"
```

You can use as much space characters as you like to separate command name and argument, but you must use at least one.